# Hide Edit mass action button for specific admin roles

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to hide or remove "Edit" button on customer_grid page for a role in admin, I added code customer_listing.xml

```
<action name="edit" class=""></action>
```

[image]
Can anyone suggest how can I do that?

Thanks you so much!

Comment: which class you mension in your above code?

Comment: Hi @Dhiren, I create a class like this, <action name="edit" class="My_Theme\Customer\Ui\Customer\EditMassAction"/> but I'm not sure how to hide it.

Comment: Actually you can not hide the options, but you can hide the action, so nothing perform on that options.